# How do I avoid login for messaging Using Python Praw script?

Tags: python, oauth, reddit, praw

I have written a script to archive submissions and comments of a certain author on Reddit. When it detects a new post I have it pm me the content.

Currently I start the session like this...

```
client = praw.Reddit(user_agent=USER_AGENT)
client.set_oauth_app_info(client_id = CLIENT_ID, client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET, redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:65010/authorize_callback")
 #log in for messaging
client.login(MY_USERNAME, MY_PASSWORD)
```

I see that using login is deprecated.  What steps do I need to take to give my script permission to "privatemessage"? All the examples I can find use login and I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `privatemessages` OAuth Scope.
Use it as a string in `get_authorize_url()`, as shown here: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/oauth.html#step-3-getting-authorization-from-the-user

List of all possible Scopes: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/oauth.html#oauth-scopes